# PHP fread by detail

Tags: php, fread

Please look at the PHP code below. It is from a download script:

```
while(ob_get_level() > 0){
    ob_end_clean();
}

set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);

$file = fopen(MATIN_FILE_PATH,"rb");   // the main file
$chunksize = 2*1024*1024;
while(!feof($file)){
    echo @fread($file, $chunksize);
    flush();
    if (connection_status() == 1){      // if client aborted
        @fclose($file);
        exit;
    }
}
@fclose($file);
exit;
```

In this code, you see that I send 2 MB per chunk. 
Imagine a client with speed of 100kb/s
After many times of debugging, I found out that when client downloads each 2MB, `fwrite` happens and `while` goes to next loop. so, what Is PHP doing at this time? is it waiting for the user to download 2MB completely and then send another 2MB? so, isn't it better that I send 10MB or 50MB per chunk?
Thanks for any detailed guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have 10 simultaneous client requests for downloading some file with this script and you have set 50MBs per chunk size. For each of the requests a new php process will be invoked, each of them demanding 50MBs of your server's memory to process `fread($file, 50*1024*1024)`. So, you will have 500MBs memory consumed.

If, as you suggested, a client speed is 100kb/s, then the probability that you have 100 simultaneous connections is not so low and you could get 100 concurrent requests, which is 5GBs of RAM already. Do you have that much or need that all?

You cannot make the user download the file faster than his actual download speed, so the chunk size does not significantly matter for this. Neither reducing the number of loops iterations will help to speed up. I have not tested this, but I think, the loop is executed faster than I/O operations with remote client. So, the only thing you should really be concerned of, is to make your server work reliably.

Comment: Thank you @abcdn for your good answer. I didn't understand a part of your answer, can you explain more plz? you said _if a client speed is 100kb/s, then the probability that you have 100 simultaneous connections is not so low_ I didn't understand what's the relation between client speed and simultaneous connections? And 1 more thing that you didn't mention in ur answer, please provide some more info. between 2 loop iterations, I mean when php `fread` first chunk and before second chunk, it might take 20 seconds that user downloads it. so What is PHP doing? is it just waiting and consuming RAM?

Comment: As for the speed, its simple. The lower the speed, the longer it takes to download the file, hence someone else may come and connect concurrently to download something from your server. If your download takes 1 hour, it is not surprising that multiple users will grab your server resources simultaneously.
As for the second part, PHP is not waiting, it is writing to the output by the `echo` directive. Naturally, it cannot write faster than the client reads.
Memory is consumed by `fread()` call, as it has to return the chunk and pass it to `echo`.
Btw, what is the purpose of logging each chunk?

Comment: I accepted your complete answer! thanks. actually understanding the behavior of PHP `fread` and loop iteration as mentioned in my questions, I logged some codes. it is temporary just for debugging (I'm going to delete those rows from code, since it's not relevant to the question). If I'm not bothering you, may you plz answer this question too? as I am setting `set_time_limit(0)` is it possible that `connection_status` occurs `TIMEOUT`? Is this `TIMEOUT` equal to (or the result of) the `timeout` set in `keep-alive` header?
THANKS for your patience of my simple questions!

Comment: It seems to me that with `set_time_limit(0)` and `ignore_user_abort(true)` together you are trying to `flush()` the whole file up to the end even to those clients who have interrupted connection already, which is unnecessary, as they are not going to receive the data any longer.
`keep-alive` header doesn't affect PHP behaviour, it is taken into consideration by the web-server (Apache or whatever you have) and it is the web-server who takes the decision on whether the connection is timed out  or not. I think, it depends on its config.

Comment: And I would also test that `flush()` to non-existing connection (i.e. when client has disconnected prior to download is completed) doesn't make the process freeze because of `ignore_user_abort(true)`; if that's so, you will have a zombie on each interrupted connection. So, better check, I am not sure about `flush()` behaviour.